# Spring batchupdate exception handling

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am working on a project where I have to make 1.5M insert\update\delete operations. I have used Springs namedParameterJDBCTemplate to do the batching. The problem statement here is that if in any particular batch any record fails to insert\update\delete , I need to know which record failed. I have done enough googling around but couldn't find anything optimal for the same.

Can Someone suggest a solution here!

updaing in batch like this

```
    int[] result = namedParamjdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, arrSqlParameterSource);
```

Where `arrSqlParameterSource` is array of `MapSqlParameterSource` which gets created while executing the business logic. We execute above code at some fixed size of array(say 1000).

Comment: Please show how you are currently trying to execute the batch update.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Not all databases support such requirements!

Comment: I am using Oracle as DB

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: Follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28775) documentation which states that with ORACLE, this isn't possible!

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer That is not actually what that documentation says: If you execute 20 statements, and the first 13 succeed, then you know the 14th failed and the rest wasn't executed.

Comment: Wanted to say IS Possible, ended up writing isn't Possible... My bad!